# Simulating selecting a file for Active Storage in irb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, polymorphism, rails-activestorage, irb

Creating a new item for Active Storage.

```
<!-- app/views/docs/_form.html.erb -->
  <%= f.label :image, "Select document or image that support this information." %>
  <%= f.file_field  :image %>
```

I'm getting a `Please review the problems below` error when I click `Create` and thought I'd see what errors happen in irb. But how do I simulate the above step.

Models:

```
# models/doc.rb
class Doc < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :image # Active Storage
  belongs_to :source
  belongs_to :docable, polymorphic: true

# models/source.rb
class Source < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :docs

# models/year.rb
class Year < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :location
  belongs_to :person
  has_many :docs, as: :docable

# models/person.rb
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :years, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :locations, through: :years
  has_many :docs, as: :docable

# models/location.rb
class Location < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :years
  has_many :people, through: :years
  has_many :docs, as: :docable
```

Where a person lived or worked at on a date is set in years. year, person and location use doc to show the reference for that information. 
The source is the title of an old book and I'm imaging various pages in the book. Later I refer to those images using docable (that's the plan).

db/structure.sql: `CREATE INDEX index_docs_on_docable_type_and_docable_id ON public.docs USING btree (docable_type, docable_id);`

Here's the session:

```
irb(main):100:0> doc = Doc.new
=> #<Doc id: nil, source_id: nil, page_no: nil, original_url: nil, basename: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, notes: nil, docable_id: nil, docable_type: nil>
irb(main):101:0> doc.save
=> false
irb(main):102:0> doc.errors.messages
=> {:source=>["must exist"], :docable=>["must exist"]}
 irb(main):104:0> doc.source_id = 4
=> 4
irb(main):105:0> doc.save
   (42.8ms)  BEGIN
  Source Load (45.3ms)  SELECT "sources".* FROM "sources" WHERE "sources"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
=> false
irb(main):106:0> doc.errors.messages
=> {:docable=>["must exist"]}
irb(main):107:0> doc.image =
```

I may have problems with the polymorphic relationship, so I'm trying to sort that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#attaching-file-io-objects

```
doc.image.attach(io: File.open('/path/to/file'), filename: 'file.jpg')
```

Comment: Thank you. Proves I have a lot to learn as I read that and missed it. Unfortunately still getting the rollback error (as I do when using the app) with no errors. `=> {:docable=>["must exist"]}`. The subject of another question unless I figure that out. But it makes it clear it something about how I've set up polymorphism. Should be clue that the error is the same whether the image has been set or not.

Comment: belongs_to relations are required by default. If you don't want it to be required, add optional: true. If it is intended to be required, then you need to set it somewhere. The  code you've provided so far does not set docable anywhere.

Comment: Thank you. I want the required. But something in how I've set the polymorphic relation is amiss. I added the other key models to the OP.

Comment: Can I get the error message to appear in the server log or in the app instead of the generic error?

Comment: Now that you added the models, I can better understand what you're trying to achieve, but the error message is still pretty clear to me. Docable must exist and does not because you're not setting it anywhere when creating the doc. docable is required on doc and doc cannot exist without docable currently.

Comment: However, your architecture seems a bit weird to me if I understand it correctly. You only want to have each image once right? But each image might contain more information that just one location or one year or one person right? Currently `Doc.belongs_to :docable`, therefore it's only allowed to have one docable.

Comment: You understand how I'm using Doc. But I don't understand `…able`. I thought some Rails magic would set docable. `docable_type` and `docable_id` are fields in `Doc`. If I think of `docable` as the image, each doc should only have one docable, but each person, location, or year can have more than one docable. It's somewhat more confusing because Doc is using ActiveStorage which is an abstraction to me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212709/discussion-between-siim-liiser-and-greg).